# Typescript, MySQL: Logging Prisma errors

Tags: mysql, prisma

I'm executing several insert and update statemens in a squence using the same prisma client variable, all wrapped in a try catch.

In the catch, I want to log the error to the database but I'm getting the error:

> Invalid `prisma.$executeRaw()` invocation:  Raw query failed. Code:
> `N/A`. Message: `N/A`

This is what my code looks like:

```
  let prisma = await new PrismaClient({
      datasources: {
          db: {
              url: dbUrl,
          },
      },
  });    

  try {
    await prisma.$executeRaw`
      INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2)
      VALUES (val1, cal2);`;

    await prisma.$executeRaw`
      INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2)
      VALUES (val1, cal2);`;

  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log('Error doing and sql insert: ' + err);    

    // Update the log item in the db with the error.
    try {
      console.log('getting ready to log sql error')
      // We can't use the prisma variable above becuase it probably died when we got the error
      // so create a new prisma variable here.
      // The exception is on the next line.
      let prisma2 = await new PrismaClient({
          datasources: {
              db: {
                  url: dbUrl,
              },
          },
      });
      await prisma2.$executeRaw`
        UPDATE FisImportLog
        SET Success = 0, Message = 'Error at: ${msg}.  ' + ${err}
        WHERE FisImportLogGUID = ${logId};`;      
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log('FIS Import *Log* Error Message: ' + err);    
      // This was really bad!!!
      // Call notification service here
    }
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this error and how I can log a prisma error to the db using prisma?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your use case for using `executeRaw` instead of using native Prisma methods? Is it possible you have a SQL syntax error or are passing values that violate database types?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks to the comment from @Shea Hunter Belsky

I was logging error messages from a Typescript try/catch and the err had lots of single quotes in it which totally corrupted the dynamic sql used for inserting the error message.  I replaced them with ticks and then all worked.

But to do this I had to use the prisma.$executeRawUnsafe instead of prisma2.$executeRaw with a string template like this:

```
let errMessage = err.toString().replace(/'/g, "`")
let errorLogSQL = `
    UPDATE FisImportLog
    SET Success = 0, Message = 'Error at: ${msg}:  ${errMessage}'
    WHERE FisImportLogGUID = '${logId}';`; 
await prisma.$executeRawUnsafe(errorLogSQL);
```

Note: I also had to wrap the ID in the where clause with single quotes where as in a string template I don't.